# Keeping only part of a regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to search for a word in text. For this I used this regex:

```
var re =/duration='\d+'/ig;
var i = text.match(re);
```

This gives me an array of matches like `"duration='300'", "duration='400'",...`

I need to get only numbers. without `duration=''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
var re = /duration='(\d+)'/ig;
var match = re.exec(text);
while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[1]
    match = re.exec(text);
}
```

Comment: @user3425017: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer works well (and I'm not sure why the OP says it is not what he/she wants). That said, here is another way to do it using the `String.replace()` method with a callback function replacement value:

```js
function getDurations(text) {
    var re =/duration='(\d+)'/ig;
    var i = [];
    text.replace(re, function(m0, m1){i.push(m1); return '';});
    return i;
}
```

Note that this technique requires no loop and is quite efficient getting the job done in a single statement.